# Will Prestige option for stat reset keep your unlocked weapons/perks?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I understand that one of the three options when you prestige is to reset all stats, but you can also use a prestige token to permanently unlock some weapon/perk - so my question is: When you reset your stats upon prestiging, will that also remove the permanently-unlocked weapon/perk that you unlocked with a prestige token?

I ask because I have an awful K/D, so I want to reset upon hitting 55, but I also want to permanently unlock a weapon.

Answer (score 5):

I just discovered a post on reddit in which a user used his token to unlock "Ghost" permanently, then selected the option to reset all stats.

He was downgraded to prestige level 0 again and lost his ghost unlock (among every other unlocked item).

So yeah - don't expect unlocked weapons/perks to remain if you reset all stats.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/redditcasual/comments/13cjv5/okay_so_ive_made_a_huge_mistakeresetting_your/

Comment: As I answered here : (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93275/black-ops-2-reset-all-stats), when you use a token to reset your stats, the multiplayer starts all over again. So you have to re-do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

When you prestige you get the option to unlock a perk/weapon permanently when you hit level 4 and unlock Create A Class where you make your custom classes. When you go to pick the gun or perk it will say at the bottom of your screen "RB to unlock permanently" (for Xbox 360 not sure about the others). So don't be scared when you see all the big locks on them, you'll still be able to get one of them.

Comment: That's not answering the question.

Answer (score -1):

From MW3 experience once you unlock a weapon using Prestige token, that weapon is always available for any class even after prestiging. I never unlocked a perk but would assume that it will work the same way as weapon unlock.

Comment: You could improve your answer by linking to an official source that confirms your statement.

Comment: Jigs is correct.
In MW3 it was the same.. You unlocked the weapon (although none of it's attachments like BO2). However until you leveled to have access to custom classes it didn't matter that it was "unlocked."

Comment: That's not answering the question, he's asking about the prestige token "reset all stats" !