# How does resetting work in Black Ops 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

If you reset all stats, does that reset you to level 1 no prestige or will you have no stats and be level 1 on first prestige?

Answer (score 5):

You will be set back to the same point as when you started up multi player the first time, that is **0 on all your stats.**

There is one thing you actually do get though, and that is a new *Fresh Start Title* / *Calling Card* to use on your player card, looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Reset all stats in Black Ops 2 is a like starting the multiplayer all over again. You're back at level 1, prestige 0, no weapons unlocked, no perks unlocked, 0 kills, 0 deaths, no calling cards, etc. It's a full reset.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

You lose all of your progress and may lead you to some frustration (to "waste your hard work")

Comment: Do you lose your prestige level as well?